# How to turn on url boxes for links in latex?

Tags: hyperref, urls

I have several links in some document. However, I would like to highlight with boxes this links in order to do not pass unoticed. Any idea of how to do this?.

Comment: This is default if you load the `hyperref` package in LaTeX with a standard class etc. Since you say nothing about which engine or format you are using, I don't know if this is relevant as you might not even be using LaTeX. If you are, you might not be using a standard class. Indeed, it is odd if there are ***links*** and no boxes if this is LaTeX since `hyperref` is the standard to create the former and also by default creates the latter. So, really, my lack of a crystal ball renders your problem something of a mystery to me.

Comment: Please, make a complete MWE (minimal working example) to show/clarify the problem.